# Read a file line by line with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file, utf-8

The following code is used to read a file line by line.

It's just a very early version, so all I want to do is display the string in the immediate window. It's working fine, except that characters such as Ä Ü Ö è à and so on are replaced by a black square with a question mark. According to the documentation, the file reader should be compatible with UTF-8 chars so I don't know what is wrong.

```
...

    Dim reader = File.OpenText(filetoimport.Text)

    Dim line As String = Nothing

    Dim lines As Integer = 0

    While (reader.Peek() <> -1)
        line = reader.ReadLine()
        If line.StartsWith("<item key=""") Then
            Dim Firstpart As String = Nothing

            Firstpart = line.Substring(11, line.IndexOf(""" value=") - 11)

            Debug.WriteLine(Firstpart)

            lines = lines + 1

            Label3.Text = lines
            Application.DoEvents()
        Else
            Label3.Text = lines
            Application.DoEvents()
        End If

    End While

...
```

The file is ANSI-encoded, not UTF-8, but the reader uses UTF-8.

Comment: You need to open the file to reading using the correct encoding. The [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383357.aspx) overload that takes an `Encoding` would probably suit your needs better.

Comment: and how would i do that? i didnt find any parameters to pass to the file..

Comment: You explore the `File` interface. There is more than just `File.OpenText`...

Comment: sure, but i cant find anything that makes more sense to me then opentext, since it is a textfile. file.open doesnt work with reader.peek()

Comment: Why use `reader.peek` at all? You can also use `File.ReadLines` (which also only makes sense in text files).

Comment: because i would know when the file is finished.. so you would use `file.open`and `file.readlines`right?

Comment: Well, by iterating over the return value of `file.ReadLines`, the loop will terminate after the last line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replaced the reader declaration with this one and now it works!

```
Dim reader As New StreamReader(filetoimport.Text, Encoding.Default)
```

Encoding.Default represents the ANSI code page that is set under Windows Control Panel.

Answer (score 19):

Like this... I used it to read Chinese characters...

```
Dim reader as StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(filetoimport.Text)
Dim a as String

Do
   a = reader.ReadLine
   '
   ' Code here
   '
Loop Until a Is Nothing

reader.Close()
```

Comment: There is no My.Computer.FileSystem on my vb.net