# Find a line in a text file and display it in a text box VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I am trying to read an entire text file. Then make the text show up in a big text box named entireTextFile. I also have smaller text boxes for single lines of the text file. I would like to display the text lines in the smaller boxes. If possible, it would help to make those lines no longer display on the big text box. Additionally I have no idea how to save a text file if a user changes the text, yet. Any help with that would be great too.
Thank you.

Example:
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CFA3.png)

```
Public Sub Display_Click()
Try
Dim latitude As String = "Lat:"
Dim longitude As String = "Long:"

fr = New StreamReader("M:\textfile\" + fileBox.Text + "")
ReadString = fr.ReadLine
Do Until (fr.Peek < 0)
ReadString = ReadString & vbCrLf & fr.ReadLine
Loop
fr.Close()
entireTextFile.Text = ReadString
If ReadString.Contains(latitude) Then
stnLat.Text = fr.ReadLine()
End If
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921080/read-a-file-line-by-line-with-vb-net  It should get you going.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to find a specific line of text that you know exists or at least a keyword or keywords in that line of text or are you asking to display each line into separate textboxes?

Comment: Both. I know the text "Lat:" exists. I'd like to find that line and display all of the text after "Lat:" in the textbox named stnLat. If need be, I can settle for displaying the entire line of text. "Lat: 43.XXXX"

Comment: If what you show in you example image is an example of your text file, it does not contain "Lat:" or "latitude" as shown in your code. There is not colon after Lat and it is an uppercase L. Maybe not much different to a human but completely different to a computer. Are you able to fill your large text box? Since you found StreamReader to open the file see if you can find StreamWriter to save the file.

Answer (score 0):

While you are looping over the text, line by line check if line contains the word you want and put it in "single_line_textbox" if it doesn't, put it into "all_lines_textbox"

```
Dim ReadLine as String = Reader.ReadLine
if ReadLine.Contains("myword") Then
    single_line_textbox.text = ReadLine
Else
    all_lines_textbox.text &= ReadLine & vbNewLine
End if
```

As for saving text to file, you can look up a guide on the itnernet, there are many of those.