# Encoding problem with file generated by Java program for a VB application

Tags: java, vb.net, encryption, encoding, notepad++

I have a tiny Java Encryption program that reads in a csv and generates an encrypted csv file to be uploaded to a VB application but the VB application after decrypting is not able to display the characters properly.

I opened the file in Notepad++ and converted it to UTF-8 in notepad++ and the VB application was able to decrypt and display all the right characters.
I then went ahead and modified my code to read in the lines from the csv using UTF-8 but I didn't work. I tried reading the file converting it to bytes and creating a new string using UTF-8 encoding and that didn't work either. Why does it work when I use notepad++ to convert to UTF-8 but not when I attempt to that in my code.

VB function

```
//each line from the encrypted file is processed by this VB RC4 function
Private Function RC4(ByVal Str As String, ByVal Pwd As String) As String

    Dim strReturnValue As String = ""
    Dim Sbox(0 To 255) As Integer
    Dim A, B, c
    Dim Key() As Byte, ByteArray() As Byte, Tmp As Byte

    If Len(Pwd) = 0 Or Len(Str) = 0 Then GoTo Exit_Function
    If Len(Pwd) > 256 Then
      Key = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(Pwd, 256)) ''StrConv(Left$(Pwd, 256), vbFromUnicode)
    Else
      Key = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Pwd)  ''StrConv(Pwd, vbFromUnicode)
    End If

    For A = 0 To 255
      Sbox(A) = A
    Next A
    A = 0 : B = 0 : c = 0
    For A = 0 To 255
      B = (B + Sbox(A) + Key(A Mod Len(Pwd))) Mod 256
      Tmp = Sbox(A)
      Sbox(A) = Sbox(B)
      Sbox(B) = Tmp
    Next A
    A = 0 : B = 0 : c = 0
    ByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Str) '' StrConv(Str, vbFromUnicode)
    For A = 0 To Len(Str) - 1
      B = (B + 1) Mod 256
      c = (c + Sbox(B)) Mod 256
      Tmp = Sbox(B)
      Sbox(B) = Sbox(c)
      Sbox(c) = Tmp
      ByteArray(A) = ByteArray(A) Xor (Sbox((Sbox(B) + Sbox(c)) Mod 256))
    Next A
    strReturnValue = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(ByteArray)  ''StrConv(ByteArray, vbUnicode)
Exit_Function:
    Return strReturnValue
  End Function
```

Java

```java
//processing line from the input file and writing to file
try
 {
FileOutputStream fos = newFileOutputStream("stackOverFlow\\EncryptedFile.csv",true);
byte [] encrypt = EncryptFile.RC4(line.getBytes(), pwd);
fos.write(encrypt);
fos.close();
}
catch (Exception e1) 
{
e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Delete the line `On Error Resume Next`. It prevents the computer from telling you if there is a problem.

Comment: I have but there is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After decompiling the VB application and reading the post below I found a solution:

[Read a file line by line with VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921080/read-a-file-line-by-line-with-vb-net)

I changed the way the Reader declaration from

Dim reader As StreamReader

to

Dim reader As New StreamReader(filetoimport.Text, Encoding.Default)